# Fullcalendar redners two calendars

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to implement Fullcalendar to my site, it is working but a second unthemed calendar shows up under my regular calendar. The second calendar doesn't contain any data only the dates of the month in a table.
Here is my calendar script:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'next'
  },
},
  locale: 'hu',
  navLinks: true,
  editable: false,
  eventLimit: true, 
  defaultView: 'listMonth',
  contentHeight: 'auto',
  events: [
      {% for item in dates %}
    {
      title: '{{ item.page.szerzo }}: {{ item.page }} ',
      start: '{{ item.datum|date:"c" }}',
       url: '{{ item.jegylink }}',
    },
     {% endfor %}
  ]
});
```

});

This is the table:
[Picture of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjZqw.png)

How can I make it disappear?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is it your full code? Possibly, it is being called from other script. I suggest you to do simple debug with console.log() and you should be able to trace it.

Comment: the code you've shown wouldn't produce two calendars. It must be something else in your page.

Comment: It was called in another script that was it! thanks!